# Looking for good substitute for calculating percentage employing integer math

Tags: math, integer, precision

I am a hobbyist programming for an embedded application.  The application requires speed.  I would like to determine whether or not a certain variable (call it "X") has passed a certain percentage (call it "Y") of another variable (call it "Z").

X, Y, and Z can all change at runtime.  Since I need speed I would like to do this using integer math as opposed to float, which incurs a speed penalty.

Are there any tricks for doing this?  I am a self trained programmer so please excuse me if this is a well known problem with a well known solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you want is to test `1*X > Z*Y` there is nothing stopping you from doing exactly this, simply define 1 (and thus 100%) to be `10^decPlaces` where `decPlaces>=2` (otherwise you won't have enough precision to do percentages as `int`s

if you need calculations to be correct to within 4 d.p. if `X = 10` then `X_fixed_precision = 100000` if Y is 30% (0.3) then `Y_fixed_precision=3000` and if `Z=10000` then `z_fixed_precision=100000000` this trick is called fixed precision arithmetic...

If you want even better performace use powers of 2 instead of 10 (its harder to translate into exactly how many decimal places this gets you but should be somewhat faster)

e.g. your code would probably look like

```
if (ONE_FIXED_PRECISION * X_fixed_precision > Z_fixed_precision * Y_fixed_precision)
   // Do something
```

where `FOO_fixed_precision = FOO * ONE_FIXED_PRECISION`

Be careful to ensure that you aren't going to get integer overflow there though - the Max value of `X * ONE_FIXED_POINT * ONE_FIXED_POINT` must be less than the maximum value you can store in a word (or double word if your using longer integer types)

Comment: Forgive the newbie question, sorry, but why (e.g.) 100*x/y > z instead of 100*x > z*y?

Comment: because that was the way i worked through the math in my head... (its been a while since ive actually had to use this technique) i'll edit, the pure multiplication way is more accurate

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks for helping out a true newb.  If you are wondering what you helped me do, I am trying to make a propeller clock similar to the hard drive clocks you can see on youtube.  Appreciate your help!

Comment: Couldn't it also be the case that in some languages you could use parentheses like 100*(x/y) > z to try to prevent overflow?  Maybe it wouldn't even be necessary to use parentheses.

Comment: if you do the division first then you lose precision - if x is 3.31, y is 33% and z is 10 and you are using 100 as your fixed precision multiplier, the test should come back true, but with integer division, `100*(331/33) = 1000` which is not strictly greater than `10*100=1000` whereas `331*100 > 1000*33`

Comment: So, is it fair to say that a decision could be made to either be more accurate or to risk an overflow?  Of course, the context of the calculation could be considered in this decision, but I am speaking in general terms.

Comment: Yes however in _most_ situations a `ONE_FIXED_PRECISION` can be chosen such that overflow is unlikely or even impossible (e.g. X and Z have upper bounds less than 2^32/1000 then `ONE_FIXED_PRECISION = 1000` guarantees no overflow and Y can have a meaningful precision of to 0.1%. (assuming you are using 32-bit integers

Comment: Cool.  Thanks again for taking the time to post.  I really appreciate it.